# Preventing direct access to php files

Tags: php, apache

Here is an example of my file structure.

```
/index.php
/inc
/inc/file1.php
/inc/file2.php
/inc/file3.php
/search.php
```

index.php includes() file1.php, file2.php, and file3.php.
 And I want them to be accessible by index.php only.

What's the most elegant solution available?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Get them outside the document root:

```
/documentroot/index.php
/inc/file1.php
/inc/file2.php
/inc/file3.php
```

So, there is no direct access to them whatsoever.

Comment: If apache, and `.htaccess` is allowed, then put an `.htaccess` file in `/inc` with the lines: `Order allow,deny` & `Deny from all`.

Answer (score 2):

In index.php you can define a constant like this:

```
define('RESTRICTED',1);
```

Then in your other pages you put this after `<?php`

```
if(!defined('RESTRICTED'))exit('No direct script access allowed!');
```

When the other pages are accessed directly the code above sees that RESTRICTED has not been set, hence it will exit.

Answer (score 1):

make a .htaccess file and put it in the inc folder

```
<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<Files *.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>
```

or put this at top of file you want to denie

```
if(strrchr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],'/')=='/file_name.php'){die;} // not good for ajax include
```