# Block access to files

Tags: php, file-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Preventing direct access to php files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930664/preventing-direct-access-to-php-files)

I want to block direct access to certain files so that they can only be used by PHP via `include` or `require`.

What I'm doing on the first line of each file is this:

```
<?php
if(stristr(__FILE__,substr($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],strrpos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],"/")+1))){
   header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
   exit;
}
?>
```

Is that a good way of doing this, or is there a better way?

Thank you.

Comment: That's not true, those are about .htaccess files. Plus I am asking for confirmation about my own practice using PHP, again **NOT** htaccess or server-related configs.

Comment: The question I explicitly marked as a duplicate makes no mention of .htaccess files. The accepted answer on that question makes no mention of .htaccess files (a comment on it does, but that smells of a reply to a deleted comment). You asked "is there a better way" - generic "How do I do this?" questions generally imply a "What is the best way". If you just want a code review, then your question is to localised for StackOverflow and you should ask on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I don't know how to see which question you marked as "exact duplicate", but the link from Quetin is to a question about server config: moving files outside the public HTML folder. I am trying to understand if the PHP code I posted is good for denying access and if not why it isn't. Simple question, simple answer (yet to come). To recap: *I am looking for a PHP solution.*

Comment: Dear `Quetin`, `deceze`, `hsz`, `Richard Harrison` and `Marc B`, you are very wrong. The "exact duplicate" question you are linking to does not have a PHP solution, but a server one which I cannot use. I guess it's fun to press buttons.

Answer (score 1):

One better option would be to move the files out of the website public area into a private directory, then use [set_include_path](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) (or equivalent server config)  to allow `include` and `requre` to find them.

Comment: Why is that better? PHP can be tricked to allow access? Or you mean it's just easier than added those lines of code to each file? Thanks.