# How to make only open your php file when refferred from a specific page or file

Tags: php

I want to make my page something like that: when I access my `php` file hrefferd through a button from my index file it should open successfully. But if I write the `php` file URL directly in the address bar it must not open. I am new in `php`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Preventing direct access to php files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6930664/preventing-direct-access-to-php-files)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `POST` request

`if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{`
    `//Code`
`}
else
{
    echo "Sorry you can't access this page directly";
}`

And in your page with the button you can use

`<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])?>" method="POST">
<input type="Submit" Value="View Page">
</form>`

Comment: seems to be not working getting This page can’t be displayed, because this site’s server might be under maintenance or there could be a programming error.500 error

Comment: @MananParagon I have done some changes if you try this code in any page that supports php it should work